# Access html element in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. I have created `html` controls with `JQuery.Ajax` so I cant have it `ID` at development time.
2. I have learned about `Request.Form["name"]` but it gets elements by `name` not `Id`. I need to access elements by `id` because my controls are radio button and I have got more than one radio button with same `name` to manage radio grouping.

What option have I left?

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way you can get controls created in JS on server side. Except Form["name"] as you have mentioned. An other way is to get these by getting Html of parent(server control) and parse that html to find your controls. But the RECOMMENDED/BEST approach is that you should use/access controls in JS that are created in JS, you can use Ajsx to post there response on server, or assign their selection to some server control.

Comment: Thanks @AmerZafar, I will consider your advise after some RnD :)

Comment: Can't use `Request.Form["id"]`?

Comment: Read second point @Bharadwaj sir :)

Comment: @Imad I am not suggesting, I ask a question there, like `Form["name"]` will give elements by `name`, so `Form["id"]` will give elements by `id`? (this is also question, not answer or suggestion) ;)

Comment: Oh.. actually `Form` is `NameValueCollection` like 'Dictionary["any_key"]' hence `name` is any key. Don't be confused with `name` key. It could be anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Done it finally..!!

I used `Request["name"]` as Amer said that its my final choice. The problem with this approach was that I was using `radio` button and I had to give same name for radio button to bind them in a single group.

like:

```
<input id="id1" type="radio" name = "groupname" />
<input id="id2" type="radio" name = "groupname" />
```

Hence I was not getting any value for `Request["id1"]` or `Request["id2"]` as this work for `name` and I was passing `id` and as name was not unique here I was not able to get the values. I changed above code to

```
<input id="id1" type="radio" name = "g1" />
<input id="id2" type="radio" name = "g2" />
```

and for grouping I wrote custom `JQuery`. Now I can get these values using `Request["g1"]` or `Request["g2"]` :)